# Copy cells between worksheets, based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel 2013 code which copies entire rows of Data from one sheet, into another, based on a selected Criteria without needing to filter.

There is a Dropdown box in **Sheet12, Cell E6**. (It is created via an Offset formula in Data Validation to read from a pivot table so the list is dynamic as new data is refreshed.)

I cannot get the IF statement, to take the value from the above mentioned cell and use that as the criteria. It only works if it is hard coded like below.

```vb
Sub CopyGRPData()

Dim lRow, cRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("Group Related Processes").Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row

For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Sheets("Group Related Processes").Range("C" & j) = "Test" Then
        cRow = Sheets("Processing Activities").Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Group Related Processes").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Processing Activities").Range("A" & cRow + 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I tried changing to typical referencing like:

```
If Sheets("Group Related Processes").Range("C" & j) = Sheets("Sheet12").Range("E6") Then
```

or

```
If Sheets("Group Related Processes").Range("C" & j) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("E6") Then
```

It gives me

> Error 438 "Object Doesnt support this property or Method"

Comment: Are you saying the code above works and you are trying to do something different?

Comment: The Code above works, but isn;t exactly what I need. So it just needs an adjustment I am unable to figure out. Where the IF statement references "Test" as a pre defined condition... I need that to reference the value in a Cell instead, as the value will change based on whats in that cell. I hope that makes sense. Its making that adjustment that creates the error above

Comment: So what code are you trying which doesn't work? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Updated to detail the code properly, I had included it but had only mentioned it loosely

Comment: What does E6 actually contain - is it a data validation dropdown?

Comment: Yes, Sheet12, Cell E6 There is a Dropdown box (Created via an Offset formula in Data Validation to read from a pivot table so the list is dynamic as new data is refreshed).

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I can't see anything immediately obvious. Are you referencing more than one workbook?

Comment: Just the multiple sheets within 1 workbook. What would you like a screenshot of sorry? The Error code just says "Error 438 Object Doesn't support this property or Method". and it will highlight in yellow that first line of the IF statement

Comment: The cell E6. If you try just changing E6 to any other cell does it then work?

Comment: I have just tried having an empty cell simple reference E6 (I.e ='Sheet12'!E6), then it does work! as a workaround I have simply added this in. The code did not want to reference a drop down box

Answer (score 0):

If the sheets are in the same workbook and this works:
If Worksheets("Group Related Processes").Range("C" & j) = "Test" ...

and this does not works:
If Worksheets("Group Related Processes").Range("C" & j) = Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("E6") ...

then: Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("E6") <> "Test"

Maybe there are spaces...